# Modelling Projectile Motion using Matlab ode45

Tags: matlab

So I am trying to model simple projectile motion (no air resistance etc) using the ode45 solver in Matlab. This is my code so far:

```
function [x,y] = trajectory_without_AR_45(v0,theta, dt)

%Path of mortar without air resistance using ode45
g = 9.81;
t_start = 0;
t_end = 100;
%Initial Conditions
y01 = 0; %initial x 
y02 = v0 * cos(theta); %finding initial velocity in x direction
y03 = 0; %initial y
y04 = v0 * sin(theta); % finding intial velocity in y direction
y0 = [y01;y02;y03;y04];
%Derivatives
dy1 = y0(2); %vx
dy2 = 0; %ax
dy3 = y0(4); %vy
dy4 = -g; %ay
dy = [dy1;dy2;dy3;dy4];
%Using ODE45
f = @ (t, y) (dy);
solution = ode45(f, [t_start, t_end], y0);
t = t_start : 0.01: t_end;
y = deval(solution, t);
plot (y(:,1), y(:,3)); %plotting trajectory
end
```

However, the plot I am getting is just a straight line which clearly is not correct. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: am304's answer is correct, the fundamental thing here is that your `f` isn't actually dependent on `t` or `y`, it's the *constant* vector `dy`. You could define `f` like `f = @(t,Y) [Y(2); 0; Y(4); -9.81];`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're not calling the ode solver properly, you only seem to be using the initial conditions to compute `dy`, which is wrong. Best to put the ode function in a separate function (file). For example, the following is in `missile.m`:

```
function dY = missile(t,Y)

  g = 9.81;
  dY(1) = Y(2); %vx
  dY(2) = 0;    %ax
  dY(3) = Y(4); %vy
  dY(4) = -g;   %ay

end
```

Which you would then call as follows:

```
t_start = 0;
t_end = 2.3; % changed to something more consistent with when y<0
v0 = 10; % made up
theta=pi/4; % made up
y01 = 0; %initial x 
y02 = v0 * cos(theta); %finding initial velocity in x direction
y03 = 0; %initial y
y04 = v0 * sin(theta); % finding intial velocity in y direction
y0 = [y01;y02;y03;y04];

opts = odeset('MaxStep',0.01,'InitialStep',0.001);
[t,y] = ode45(@missile, [t_start, t_end], y0, opts);

plot(t,y)
legend('x','dx','y','dy')
```

which gives the following results:

[image]